# IOS How do i do a proper counting when comparing same item?

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, dictionary, count

I have an array call arrFinalValues that contains 2 object, one is item and the other one is date of that item. I want to do a counting of similar item that occur on the same date in the array. It seems that i once i log it out. The counter is wrong. 
He is the output of the array when i log it out:

```
value of severity (
        {
        Severity = Warning;
        createdDate = "2015-12-09";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 2;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Warning;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-05";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    }
)
```

As you can see during 2015-12-08 there are 2 noOfOccurence at index 1. But at index 2 there are also another 2015-12-08 that has 1 noOfOccurence. It is wrong as this date at index 1 and 2 are the same the total noOfOccurence for 2015-12-08 should be 3.

Here is the code that i use:

```
 dictionForSeverity = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //code for same severity type for the same date
    for (int i = 0; i < feeds.count; i++)
    {
        int count =1;
        BOOL flag = false;
        for (int j = i+1; j< feeds.count; j++)
        {
            if ([[feeds objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToDictionary:[feeds objectAtIndex:j]])
            {
                count++;
                flag = true;
                [feeds removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }


        if (flag == true)
        {
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] forKey:@"Severity"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForSeverity copy]];
        }
        else
        {
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] forKey:@"Severity"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForSeverity copy]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"value of severity %@",arrFinalValues);

    //giving values according to date manage/replace object of an array according to date
    for (int i=0; i<arrFinalValues.count; i++)
    {
        long indexOfObject;
        NSLog(@"%@",[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] );
        if ( [[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Informational"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrInformation replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Warning"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrWarning replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrCritical replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Emergency"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrEmergency replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: while looping through the array u can create a dic where the key is the date and the occurance is the value...then if the date repeat just increment the value with that date key, it wont create duplicate since key cant be duplicated...not sure if there's better way

Comment: I believe is some part of this code has an error because when i log it out it can do a count to 2 when there is a match case. But i don't know why it cannot count to the 3rd number when there is a match case at 2015-12-8.

Comment: probably because u do the `if`, i saw u just replace the index in complicated way but not just `+=1` it, maybe those index is where ur code is wrong

Comment: After i change to +=1 it says out of bound index error. I tried remove the flag already but it still didn't do the correct counting.

Comment: because its `index`, not `int`, it can get out of bound, if u want to count something i think u should use int instead...

Comment: sry, which part of the code you meant?

Comment: the for loop that u start counting the date i mean

Comment: but i am using int for the count isn't it?

Comment: sorry but what u want is that the `noOfOccurence` should be 3 for all of the `2015-12-08` date? or there should be only 1 of that `2015-12-08` date?

Comment: for example during 2015-12-08 there are 3 APPLE. i want noOfOccurance to be 3.

Comment: who can answer my question please!